# Rails background task on post request, returns json on completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process

I'm sure that someone has solved this problem before, I'm keen to learn from your experiences.

Architecture:
Server A is a web server
Server B is an API server
Server C is a datasource

User fills out a form on server A
Server A submits a POST request to server B
Server B grabs some data from server C, creates an image, uploads image to server A, returns the resulting URL as a response to server A.

The workflow on server B is quite critical, it needs to be responsive at all times, it also needs to service many requests. Hopefully there will be thousands of active users on server A.

My question is this: How do I active the end result without locking up the Rails app on server B?

I've done a proof of concept with the data fetch and image creation in the action controller on server B. I'm almost certain that this will not perform well and give a good user experience.

With regard to uploading the image to server A, I'm able to use SFTP but am considering mounting server A's target folder locally on server B.. Hopefully this will reduce unnecessary logons.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

You can look [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). And there are many gems available like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) and so on. Using `delayed_job` you can do as follows:

```
def get_reponse_from_server2  #create a method in your model which does stuff for you
  #do your stuff
end

handle_asynchronously :get_reponse_from_server2
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion codeit.

what I really need is some kind of callback so that my actioncontroller can pass a suitable response to server a